# Как запоминать действия пользователя telegram python bot

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telebot

Ответ получен спасибо огромное!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

сделал бота в телеграмме и возникла такая проблема.

Пользователь пишет то что ему надо, а в конце все его сообщения отправились ему же

Как сделать так что все его сообщения показались в конце?

Comment: хм, пользователь пишет что ему надо в один период времени?

Comment: нет, не в один. ему задается вопрос, он на него отвечает и так 4 раза. И в конце надо вывести то что он написал 4 раза ему же

Comment: Бот задаёт 4 вопроса, на которые пользователь отвечает и после последнего вопроса бот отправляет все ответы пользователя, верно?

Comment: да, совершенно верно

Answer (score 2, accepted):

исходя из комментариев можно воспользоваться `bot.register_next_step_handler`:

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def first_q(message):
    send = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'первый вопрос')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(send, two_q)


def two_q(message):
    global answers
    answers = []
    first_answer = message.text
    answers.append(first_answer)

    send = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'второй вопрос')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(send, three_q)


def three_q(message):
    two_answer = message.text
    answers.append(two_answer)

    send = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'третий вопрос')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(send, four_q)


def four_q(message):
    three_answer = message.text
    answers.append(three_answer)

    send = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'четвёртый вопрос')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(send, end)


def end(message):
    four_answer = message.text
    answers.append(four_answer)

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, '{}'.format(''.join(answers)))
```

но `global` зло, попробуйте с классом, [здесь есть пример](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/blob/master/examples/step_example.py)

Comment: Выглядит многообещающим, я попробую это интегрировать.

Comment: Я тебя люблю! Спасибо бро!!!

Comment: Пользуйтесь на здоровье)

Answer (score 0):

Требуется сделать словарь где по айди пользователя будет прикрепляться список его действий:

```
users_actions = {1:[...], 2:[...]}
```

Потом используя какую либо команду брать список действий и возможно очищать его.

Намного лучше будет если вы покажете пример кода, и скажете что именно требуется сделать, так как для разных задач будет разное решение.